# Checking if Interface Type is CLI in PHP

Tags: php, command-line-interface

It looks like there are two typical ways to determine if a script is running via command line.

1. `if ( defined('STDIN') ) # Running via CLI`
2. `if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') # Running via CLI`

Since they're both used, and recommended, I assume they both work well. My question is: are there any fringe cases where one would fail? Which is preferred, and why?

Comment: I think this is interesting

Comment: IMO #2 is more explicit - It's checking exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Alternative, test for $argv: if running in cli, then it will be an array with at least one entry (the php script name); but I always use option #2 and never failed me yet, though there are a few potential "fringe" values like `embed` that might be returned

Comment: @markBaker: `$argv` can be disabled using `register_argc_argv = 0`. IMO, it's best to use `PHP_SAPI`...

Comment: @Elias - never having tried disabling argc_argv in CLI php.ini, does it actually disable it, and is there any way you can pass additional arguments to your cli script if it's disabled?

Comment: @MarkBaker: I haven't tried it with argv disabled, either, but `getopt` might still work, as, perhaps `$_SERVER['argv']` will still work (but the docs aren't 100% clear on that, it seems to suggest it won't be available, though). I know there's a way to read the arguments from `php://stdin`, too, but that's just masochism IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on `if (defined('STDIN'))` ever. Simply because, if the `STDIN` constant *isn't* defined, I can define it myself:

```
defined('STDIN') || define('STDIN', 'random value');
```

that would have any of the following code, using `if (defined('STDIN'))` believing it's running on the command line, whereas `PHP_SAPI` will *always* be defined.
Another thing you have to take into account is *namespaces*. Sure, this affects both checks, but you could also use [the `php_sapi_name` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) to be sure, or simply:

```
if (\PHP_SAPI === 'cli')
```

Which, to my eye, is more readable than:

```
if (defined('\\STDIN'))
```

So basically, use any of the *three* options, but be aware that `STDIN` can be a user-defined constant, too. `PHP_SAPI` or the return value of `php_sapi_name` is always going to be astring (AFAIK), and you know what value to expect when running a CLI script: `'cli'`. Though, if for some reason you don't trust that, I have seen people do this:

```
if (stristr(PHP_SAPI, 'cli') && strpos(PHP_SAPI, 'cli') === 0)
```

But that's just paranoid, IMHO.
Some just check `$argv`, but that implies the `register_argc_argv` setting is enabled, which it is by default, but [it can be disabled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv), which you could, in turn, counter with something like:

```
#!/var/bin/php -n
<?php
    if (!is_array($argv))
    {
        exit();
    }
```

by using `/path/to/php -n`, you're not using any ini file, so default settings will be used, and the since the default setting for `register_argc_argv` is 1, `$argv` will be available.